# Can we use boost format for out of sequence ordering

Tags: c++, boost

Lets go to the code directly

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string strtemplate="First:%1%, Second:%2%";
int main()
{
    vector<string> v;
    v.push_back("first");
    v.push_back("second");
#if 0
    cout<<str(boost::format(strtemplate) % v[1] % v[0])<<endl;
#else
    boost::format fmter(strtemplate);
    for(int i=0;i<2;++i)
    {
            fmter % v[i];
    }
    cout<<str(fmter)<<endl;
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output is the one inside if.
 The need is that, I might get the values in out of order but want them to be place in my pre-formatted string.
**Note** : I have used a vector here just for illustration so traversing the vector is reverse order is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

In case your vector is in reverse order for example, why not have a format template as follows?

```
"First: %3%, Second %2%, Third: %1%.";
```

You will need to know the order of the input vector in relation to the order of the slots in your string beforehand though, if that is what you are asking. Otherwise, you would need to do some analysis on the input vector, and build the format string during runtime, which sort of defeats the purpose.

I highly recommend you to look into the [`fmt`](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) library for string formatting, it is much more lightweight than Boost format, and also much faster. There is work underway to get it into the standard.